# Tiled background image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Trying to create a tiled background image for a top down game. The SKScene is 8000,8000 and instead of creating a couple very large sprites I am trying to tile it to improve performance.

```
 var coverageSize = CGSizeMake(8000,8000); 
    var textureSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); 
    var backgroundCGImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"].CGImage; //this line returns several errors.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(coverageSize.width, coverageSize.height));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, textureSize, backgroundCGImage);
    UIImage *tiledBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:tiledBackground.CGImage];
    SKSpriteNode *backgroundTiles = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];
    backgroundTiles.yScale = -1; 
    backgroundTiles.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [self addChild:backgroundTiles];
```

Comment: you cant have a texture that big, largest is 4096x4096 on newer devices, 2048x2048 on smaller devices

Comment: I know, that is why am trying to tile it with smaller textures. Having smaller textures meshed together to create 8000x8000 would elevate that issue, no?

Comment: I know I am writing an answer

Comment: A detailed blog post that covers this repeated tiling issue can be found here: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do tiles is you create a node used to draw your tiles

You draw the amount of tiles that fits the screen into this special tile

use:

```
 var texture = self.view!.textureFromNode(drawingTile, crop: CGRectMake(-column.width, -row.height, self.frame.width + column.width , self.frame.height + row.height));
```

To convert this node to a texture
now remove all nodes from the drawing node

add in the a new node to the drawing node using this texture.

we now have our background in one node.

when you need to scroll, shift the drawing node, then you draw the 1 row and 1 columns worth of tiles that are missing.  Do this only when you need your drawing mode has shifted so much that you have a gap on the screen to fill in.  Use the above code again to create a new drawing mode texture.  Rinse, repeat

Comment: I am not sure I understand. use `var bgimage : SKNode!` then `var texture = self.view!.textureFromNode(bgimage, crop: CGRectMake(-column.width, -row.height, self.frame.width + column.width , self.frame.height + row.height));` followed by adding the node to the scene `self.addchild(world)` ?? or is that missing something?

Comment: I am assuming world is your background?

Comment: ok, you only add this node once,  this will be the node that you draw with

Comment: So adding it to the `didMoveToView` column and row are showing syntax errors unresolved identifiers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117117/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-bariiiiiiicode).